# How to export a chat thread in Tinder app?

Tags: chat, export

I have a chat on Tinder that I do not want to lose. Is there any way (even against payment) to export that chat thread to pdf, txt, excel, etc.?

Comment: Are you on rooted phone?

Answer (score 1):

All the Tinder messages are stored in `/data/data/com.tinder/db/tinder.db.`
Use [Root Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=root%20explorer&c=apps&docType=1&sp=CAFiDwoNcm9vdCBleHBsb3JlcnoCGACKAQIIAQ%3D%3D%3AS%3AANO1ljIucBM&hl=en) and extract the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can save a "full page screenshot" using a third-party app like [LongShot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.leavjenn.longshot&hl=en_US).